# Cannot boot from new Ubuntu-Gnome 16.04 LTS installation in UEFI or CSM mode

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot

I have a toshiba satellite laptop that has an option to switch between UEFI and CSM/BIOS mode. I was able to successfully install 16.04 Ubuntu-Gnome in EUFI mode, but upon rebooting and selecting to boot from hard disk. I get an error informing me no bootable drive has been found.

What is the appropriate step to take to diagnose the reason I cannot boot from a successful Ubuntu-Gnome LTS 16.04 installation?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not UEFI, but Secure Boot. You need to disable Secure Boot in UEFI Setup, boot from a live Linux CD, install it and then reboot to continue. In case it still doesn't work, then use CSM, since some PCs have weird issues.

Also be sure to confirm that nothing is wrong with your HDD.

Comment: Ubuntu should work with Secure Boot. They included this quite a while back, though no entirely solid info is available.

Comment: It should, true, but it sometimes needs adding keys and such (as in my case)

Comment: Turns out my computer has had secure boot off the entire time, so that can't be it. I tried CSM but that doesn't work either. On your second point, I'm not sure how I would go about gathering status of my hard drive without an OS already installed.